# How can you access data that's nested like this in a csv file?

Tags: javascript, parsing, d3.js

Here is an example of an entry in my dataset.

```
1: Object { budget: 300000000, genres: "[{\"id\": 12, \"name\": \"Adventure\"}, {\"id\": 14, \"name\": \"Fantasy\"}, {\"id\": 28, \"name\": \"Action\"}]", revenue: 961000000 }
```

Now, I can access budget and revenue just fine, but I want to be able to access the names in genres. I was using JSON.parse, a la

```
const genre = JSON.parse(data['genres']);
```

But I was getting an error that the character in line 1 column 1 of the JSON was undefined. Is that the bracket? How can I access the names in this data?

Comment: also, I tried to use replace, but I don't think I was doing it right, so that may be why it hasn't worked out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://runkit.com/embed/j8c5yuqgppji

```js
let A = { budget: 300000000, genres: "[{\"id\": 12, \"name\": \"Adventure\"}, {\"id\": 14, \"name\": \"Fantasy\"}, {\"id\": 28, \"name\": \"Action\"}]", revenue: 961000000 }

const genres = JSON.parse(A.genres);
console.log(genres[0].name);
```

Comment: A.genres is undefined. When replaced with A['genres'[0].name], returns undefined

Comment: @rs3 Try it in the above link. It worked without any issue.

Comment: @rs3, see the updated answer. The json is copied from your OP.